# Validation(Enable) of radio buttons & submit button from a checkbox using Jquery Optimization

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Below is my code, after searching so much over the internet; i am not able to do this simple thing of validation.

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#myText').click(function(){
           $('#radio1').removeAttr('disabled','disabled');
           $('#radio2').removeAttr('disabled','disabled');
           $('#radio3').removeAttr('disabled','disabled');
           $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled','disabled');
         })
});

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <input type="checkbox" id="myText" value="Click it!">Click it!</input>
    <br/>
    <br/>

    <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="gok" value="Radio 1" disabled="disabled"> Radio 1</input>
    <br/>
    <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="gok" value="Radio 2" disabled="disabled"> Radio 2</input>
    <br/>
    <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="gok" value="Radio 3" disabled="disabled"> Radio 3</input>
    <br/>
    <button type="button" id="submit" disabled="disabled"> Submit</button>
    </body>
    </html>
```

The checkbox above when checked; the radio buttons gets enabled and submit button is also enabled. I dont think this is a optimized solution; Please help me get a code which has optimized version like 
1) if i keep radio & submit buttons in a div and try using the id of div and inside radio buttons are enabled
2) In jquery, i can run a iterator kinda thing which will reduce my code of lines

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: fyi you're using removeAttr wrong - `$('#radio1').removeAttr('disabled');` <-- should be how you use it.. But you should really be using .`prop('disabled',true/false')` if you are on jQuery 1.6+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using an `id` for each element use the `class` attribute.

Try this - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/HN3Ba/6/)

Comment: id helps to select exactly the unique element that has this id , class selects all the elements that have the same class

Comment: most times you won't want to use the class as that would be used for unrelated radio buttons. You'd most of times be better of using the radio group name, thus applying your logic only for all radio buttons that are part of the same group. In this case it would be something like `$('input[name=gok]').removeAttr('disabled')`

Answer (score 1):

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#myText').click(function(){
    $('#enableMe').children().removeAttr('disabled'); // or $('#enableMe').children().prop('disabled',true/false')
  });
});
```

**html:**

```
<div id = 'enableMe'>
  <input type="checkbox" id="myText" value="Click it!">Click it!</input> <br/> <br/>

  <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="gok" value="Radio 1" disabled="disabled"> Radio 1</input> <br/>
  <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="gok" value="Radio 2" disabled="disabled"> Radio 2</input> <br/>
  <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="gok" value="Radio 3" disabled="disabled"> Radio 3</input> <br/>
  <button type="button" id="submit" disabled="disabled"> Submit</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just do

```
$('#myText').click(function(){
       // if this is all you are going to have in your html just
       // $(this).siblings().prop('disabled',false) would work
       $(this).siblings('input[type=radio],#submit').prop('disabled',false);
 })
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cj3zY/

fyi you're using removeAttr wrong -

```
$('#radio1').removeAttr('disabled'); //<-- should be how you use it..
```

But you should really be using .prop if you are on jQuery 1.6+

```
$(element).prop('disabled',true/false);
```

[.prop() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

> Properties generally affect the dynamic state of a DOM element without changing the serialized HTML attribute. Examples include the value property of input elements, the disabled property of inputs and buttons, or the checked property of a checkbox. The .prop() method should be used to set disabled and checked instead of the .attr() method.

If you want to toggle the disabled property depending on the checkbox.. you can do it like this

```
$('#myText').click(function(){
       $(this).siblings('input[type=radio],#submit').prop('disabled',!this.checked);
})​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cj3zY/1/